# VTK 3D model displayed in web browser via XTK - how to test and analyze

Tags: 3d, webgl, visualization, vtk, xtk

I'm going to load a 3d model of a knee (saved as .vtk file, created in VTK ) into web browser by XTK library.

I have to prepare small assesment of this and analyze the results...

I'm wondering which factors I should take into consideration - loading time of the model? checking out the differences between web browsers that support WebGL?

Comment: You performed it successfully?...what is the file format of .vtk file you used?....are there any customizations needed for .vtk file to be made useful for loading into xtk?..please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check:

1- loading time (depends on your network connection)

2- parsing time (depends on your machine)

3- frame rates

4- if it looks correct or not

5- which browsers are supported (desktop, mobiles, tablets)

etc.

I would also compare it to natives apps, suck as a simple vtk app or slicer.

My 2 cts